# What's the Ideal Way to Swap Entries in the $PATH environment variable?

Tags: linux, macos, shell-script, environment-variables

In Linux and/or Mac OSX, what is the best way to automate moving an entry in the $PATH environment variable to the front of the value like this:

/foo/bar:/one/two/three:/opt/local/bin:/home/user/bin

Becomes

/home/user/bin:/foo/bar:/one/two/three:/opt/local/bin

Currently I'm using sed to accomplish this, but I'd like to know if there's a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the simplest:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"}{print $4,$1,$2,$3}' <<< $PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

Quickly, you could write:

```
dir=/home/user/bin
PATH=$dir:${PATH//:$dir/}
```

If you have something like

```
PATH=/first:/second:/home/user/bin/subdir:/home/user/bin
```

then this is more robust:

```
tmp=":$PATH:"
tmp=$dir${tmp//:$dir:/:}
PATH=${tmp%:}
```